# How do I add plugin used in Cordova project to iOS native project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cordova, webrtc

I've used [this plugin](https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc) and built a chat application in Cordova (platform iOS). I need to now integrate this into a separate native iOS app. I followed the steps mentioned [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/webview.html). Everything seems to have worked except I'm not able to utilize my plugin and I'm getting the following error

```
CDVPlugin class iosrtcPlugin (pluginName: iosrtcplugin) does not exist.
```

How do I add this plugin to the native iOS app?

Comment: are you trying to use Cordova plugin in the iOS native app? if yes then it will be not directly possible as a native project will not find Cordova classes like CDVPlugin etc... better you find native framework directly for the chat

Comment: The plugin was used in the Cordova app. So in case I need to merge the apps, is there no way of bring that plugin into the new project?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has the same issue, I fixed my problem by adding the iOS code to the Cordova app (instead of the other way around which I was trying earlier).